# how to search inside two JSON files at a time in PHP

Tags: php, json, search

I have two JSON files of same format, forexample

1st JSON File

```
{
  "data": {
    "business": {
      "id": "3NzA0ZDli",
      "customers": {
        "pageInfo": {
          "currentPage": 1,
          "totalPages": 695,
          "totalCount": 1389
        },
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "QnVzaW5lc3M6Z",
              "name": "Joe Biden",
              "email": "joe@mail.com"
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "QnVzaW5lc3M6Z",
              "name": "MULTIMEDIA PLUMBUM",
              "email": "mdi@mail.com"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2nd JSON file

```
{
  "data": {
    "business": {
      "id": "3NzA0ZDli",
      "customers": {
        "pageInfo": {
          "currentPage": 2,
          "totalPages": 695,
          "totalCount": 1389
        },
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "QnVzaW7dQ8N",
              "name": "Mark",
              "email": "mark@mail.com"
            }
          },
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "QnVzaW5l5Gy9",
              "name": "Trump",
              "email": "trump@mail.com"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Each user has a unique "id", I want to get their id by searching their name in php, how can I do this

This is my PHP script

```
$json1 = file_get_contents("1.json");
$json2 = file_get_contents("2.json");

$result1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$result2 = json_decode($json2, true);

foreach ($result2 as $k => $v) {
    if ($v['data']['business']['edges']['customers']['node']['name'] == "Trump") break;
}
echo $result[$k]['data']['business']['edges']['customers']['node']['name'];  //I want to get id for trump "QnVzaW5l5Gy9"
```

Each user has a unique "id", I want to get their id by searching their name in php. How can I get id by searching name in both files at a time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looping through json file it will search inside of "data" so you can't use `$v['data']`

Also since `edges` is also array that have same values and you want to search inside of it you must make loop on that also

Here is example

```
foreach ($result2 as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v['business']['customers']['edges'] as $val) {
        if ($val['node']['name'] == 'Trump') {
            echo '<pre>';
            // and now you can access any of those values, echo $val['node']['id'];
            print_r($val['node']);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [id] => QnVzaW5l5Gy9
    [name] => Trump
    [email] => trump@mail.com
)
```

**EDIT**

Since you want to search in both files at a same time you can put them into array and then use it like this

```
$json1 = file_get_contents("1.json");
$json2 = file_get_contents("2.json");

$result1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$result2 = json_decode($json2, true);

$joined_result = array($result1, $result2);

foreach($joined_result as $val) {
    // this will take all nodes where you will search
    $node = $val['data']['business']['customers']['edges'];

    foreach ($node as $value) {
        if ($value['node']['name'] == 'Trump') {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($value['node']);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, it did not work for me, it returned an empty page. can you help please

Comment: @ranawseef you are getting empty page because of name not found or when you try to get file from url its returning null, can you please provide links where files are ? and show piece of code how do you getting file content

Comment: i just replaced your code with mine, it returns an empty page because no name found. I am getting json files using file get content function and their is no error on getting json file. The problem is with searching name ...

Comment: $json1 = file_get_contents("1.json");
$json2 = file_get_contents("2.json");

$result1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$result2 = json_decode($json2, true);    
    rest is your code  $joined_result = array($result1, $result2);

foreach($joined_result as $val) {
    // this will take all nodes where you will search
    $node = $val['data']['business']['customers']['edges'];
etc

Comment: @ranawseef i updated code EDIT and i get result back, i took those 2 json files you posted in first post

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions there, no?

The first question I get is "How to get the ID for a certain name"

```
    $node = $result2['data']['business']['customers']['edges']['node'];
    if ($node['name'] == "Trump") echo $node['id'];
```

Almost your code, but I echo the ID when the name matches "Trump".

The second question I see is "How do search both json data at once"

```
$json1 = file_get_contents("1.json");
$json2 = file_get_contents("2.json");

$result1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$result2 = json_decode($json2, true);

$all_data = [$result1, $result2];

foreach($all_data as $data) {
  $node = $data['data']['business']['customers']['edges']['node'];
  if ($node['name'] == "Trump") echo $node['id'];
}
```

Transforming both json data to be in an array and then simply looping over the whole array should do the trick.

Comment: Also so switched your "customers" and "edges" key